# O que resta para configurar com Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

As configurações que costumo usar com o *spring* são baseadas em classe Java, como nesse exemplo https://github.com/matheussilvasantos/autocomplete.

Caso este projeto utilizasse o *spring boot*, quais configurações ainda seriam necessárias para configurar nas classes?

Olhei um exemplo em que para configurar um interceptor com o *spring boot*, criavam uma classe para configurar, então tem um limite para o *spring boot*, até onde é possível configurar com o *application.properties*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Configurando com Spring Boot

> Caso este projeto utilizasse o spring boot, quais configurações ainda seriam necessárias para configurar nas classes?

Na verdade, você poderia remover parte das configurações, pois a ideia do Spring Boot é justamente juntar os componentes mais usados do Spring usando algumas convenções e evitar que você precise fazer isso manualmente.

Tanto que o Spring Boot na verdade tem "sabores" prontos para os tipos mais comuns de aplicação. [Veja a lista aqui](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter-poms).

Num [exemplo simples de projeto web](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/), você pode conferir que a única configuração necessário foi:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

## Application.properties

> Olhei um exemplo em que para configurar um interceptor com o spring boot, criavam uma classe para configurar, então tem um limite para o spring boot, até onde é possível configurar com o application.properties?

O `application.properties` não é um substituto para configuração da aplicação. Ele é apenas um facilitador para as variações de configuração mais comuns. Isso ajuda bastante na maioria dos casos, mas numa aplicação não trivial é quase inevitável você não ter que usar configurações via anotações ou mesmo via XML, dependendo do seu intuito.

[Veja aqui a lista de configurações mais comuns](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).

A forma recomendada para configuração é usando anotações. Por exemplo, para declarar um novo *bean*, basta declarar um método numa classe de configuração qualquer cujo retorno é a instância e anotar o método com `@Bean`.

Não tem nada de errado nem efeitos colaterais indesejados em fazer esse tipo de configuração, portanto não gaste tempo tentando fugir disso, a não ser que seja para usar alguma funcionalidade padrão facilmente ativada pelo `application.properties`.

## Exemplos e migração

Eu tenho [vários exemplos de projetos usando Spring Boot no meu Github](https://github.com/utluiz/spring-examples).

Acredito que a forma mais fácil de você usar SpringBoot no seu projeto seja primeiramente mudar a configuração (`pom.xml`) de acordo com os exemplos, depois a configuração da aplicação (anotações e métodos das classes de configuração).

Provavelmente não precisará de qualquer mudança no sistema em si, a não ser talvez mover algum de lugar para se adequar ao padrão do Spring Boot. Então, é só uma questão de transpor a forma de configurar e com o tempo você vai descobrindo o que o Spring Boot oferece com maior facilidade.

Porém, Spring Boot não é muito mais que o Spring com convenções, então uma boa aplicação pode não ter ganho algum em migrar.

Comment: saberia me dizer se consigo configurar um interceptor(HandlerInterceptorAdapter) como no Spring MVC no Spring Boot?

Comment: @Matheus A princício, [sim](http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-handlerinterceptor-annotation-example-webmvcconfigureradapter), mas tem mais de um jeito. Por favor, evite comentários fora do assunto, faça uma nova pergunta.